# What projection / coordinate system are used for Maps.me?

Tags: coordinate-system, portable-gis, maps.me

I need to import data into Maps.me but since I assume there is not OTF reprojection, I need to know the CRS I must use.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Maps.me are based on OSM data so probably they use the same CRS, which iss EPSG 3857.

Comment: The native CRS in OSM is actually EPSG:4326 but by looking at the coordinates of the polygons in the source code at https://github.com/mapsme/omim/tree/master/data/borders they are probably in EPSG:3857.